# show django messages inside form_invalid of FormView

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

How can i show a message when using FormView class when form is invalid? I could show the message in form_valid function but no idea on form_invalid as i am using self.get_context_data.

This is what i have done to show message when the form is valid

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    messages.success(self.request, '{0} added successfully'.format(name))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

How can i use message here?

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Comment: yes you can... you can see this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example)

Comment: i want to show message in template as 'you have already posted' instead of form errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this one;

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    name = 'john'
    messages.warning(self.request, '{0} error'.format(name))

    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(request=self.request, form=form))
```

**Explanation:**

`messages.warning(self.request, '{0} error'.format(name))` put before `self.render_to_response(**kwargs)`, why? this for updating your `self.request` with your message.

and `self.render_to_response(**kwargs)` is using `**kwargs` parameters.
one of it for the `form` and `request` fields. see this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.render_to_response).

Comment: yes this worked. Can you please clear me why using request=self.request inside get_context_data worked? Is it because, you have overriden self.request in messages.warning?

Comment: I have marked your answer as solved. Please can you explain my above question in the answer as well?